# Expire cookie set through FormAuthentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication, membership, logout

I have used MemberShipUser API on Login we are validating user and creating FormAuthentication

```
FormAuthentication.SetAuth(username, false);
```

now if user doesnot logout and close the browser directly FormAuthentication.SignOut method is not called.

due to which when we reopen the website the user is already logged in.

Comment: There'a a setting in the web.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either configure the timeout value to an appropriate number or use cookie less forms authentication.

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"
           protection="All"
           timeout="30" <----------------------------Tune this
           name=".ASPXAUTH" 
           path="/"
           requireSSL="false"
           slidingExpiration="true" <--------------------- Tune this
           defaultUrl="default.aspx"
           cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" <--------------------- Or Turn off cookies
           enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx#pagexplained0002_cookielessforms](http://Explained%3a%20Forms%20Authentication%20in%20ASP.NET%202.0)

Answer (score 0):

The authentication cookie will still be valid. When the user opens the site again, the cookie says the user is still logged in.

You can make the cookie short lived so it's more likely to have expired:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="Login/" timeout="5"/>
</authentication>
```

but afaik, if the user doesn't log out they won't be immediately logged out.

^^Unless you don't use cookies as hasan-khan says (it passes an id in the querystring which doesn't really look very nice.)